# W3Schools é uma referência horrível, certo?

Tags: debate, respostas, voto-contra

Como já é de costume no [SO<sup>en</sup>](http://www.stackoverflow.com), nas respostas, o pessoal dar *downvote* e comentar informando que [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) tem [péssima reputação](http://www.w3fools.com/), pelo fato de estar sempre desatualizado e também por inúmeros motivos citados no link, estou apenas repassando essa informação para informação pessoal, aqui do [SO<sup>pt</sup>](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), pois é sempre bom sabermos diferenciar as referências para que não haja conhecimento errôneo mediante à nossos usuários.

Vocês concordam?

**Caso alguém tenha algo contra, utilize de seus argumentos.**

Comment: Não acho que apenas por conter referencias do W3Schools, a questão deve receber downvotes, já que como vocês mesmo citaram, o problema é não está atualizado, e se é algo que já há a muito tempo como padrão, a fonte se torna aceitável (se o conteúdo estiver correto). Não é questão do local e sim do conteúdo que é exposto. Se fosse assim sites desconhecidos, com bom conteúdo deveriam  cair nessa mesma regra. Só discordo do ponto que você querer impor uma regra de que isso é errado (de forma geral).

Comment: Não concordo que é uma referência horrível. Pode até haver coisas erradas (que até onde eu vejo, quando alguém reclama eles já corrigem também), mas no geral está certo e funciona. Afinal, se não funcionasse os tryit disponíveis não funcionariam. Talvez para servidor tenha mais erros. Mas qual referência da web é tão confiável assim? Mesmo o manual do PHP eu nem passaria perto de olhar em português, porque está sempre desatualizado. Acho que o erro está em quem confia demais em uma referência, o autodidatismo nos ensina que é necessário sempre procurar de várias fontes.

Answer (score 26):

O W3Schools é uma referência ruim? Sim. Isso justifica downvotes em respostas que o citem? Não! Nem mesmo no SO em inglês (embora muitas pessoas lá votem contra só por isso).

Downvotes são para respostas incorretas ou muito ruins. Se a resposta está correta e cita o W3Schools, eu costumo seguir o link para ver se há algum problema na documentação citada. Se houver, eu deixo um comentário apontando que a referência não é boa, e sugerindo uma alternativa (documentação oficial do W3C, MDN, http://webplatform.org, manual do PHP etc).

Um porém: o W3Schools já foi pior, mas *parece* que estão correndo atrás do prejuízo. Originalmente o site do w3fools continha uma grande lista de problemas na documentação deles sobre diversas tecnologias. Em certo ponto, essa lista foi removida (acho que não conseguiram mantê-la sincronizada com as correções do W3Schools). Independentemente disso, a quantidade de falhas era tão grande que dificilmente eles conseguiram corrigir tudo, por isso eu sempre desconfio do que o W3Schools diz.

Comment: concordo parcialmente com sua resposta, embora em todos os casos eu sempre aviso que o W3Schools, em geral, é uma referência ruim, mesmo que a tal referência usada pelo autor não esteja errada, pois eu vejo o site em uma maneira geral, para que ele não utilize novamente e venha a errar. Mas concordo muito com a atitude de sugerir uma alternativa, porém a questão de dar downvote é de se discutir... porque você poderia meio que "forçar" o usuário a procurar uma referência melhor ou remover a referência da sua resposta, dando downvote.

Comment: logo apos que o usuário, removesse a referencia ruim ou substituisse por uma boa, você tambem removeria seu downvote.

Comment: Concordo que é útil deixar o comentário mesmo quando não há problemas no link específico, e na verdade faço isso muito. Mas não concordo com esse downvote "de pressão". Só vou votar contra se a resposta estiver errada mesmo.

Comment: poisé, cada um tem sua opinião, na minha o usuário não vai ligar na maioria das vezes se você apenas deixar a referência ali, mas se você dar um downvote ele vai meio que sentir uma obrigação de melhorar suas referências.