# Uma pergunta que pede uma informação canônica é opinião?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

Eu respondi a pergunta [Onde devo aprender classes e métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201869/101) com a maior tranquilidade porque dá para responder canonicamente. Mas ela foi fechada como baseada em opiniões.

Achei que não fazia sentido e até fui ver [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101) para ver se caia em algum dos 6 itens que classificam uma pergunta **subjetiva ruim**. Aí me dei conta que estava perdendo tempo, ali só fala de perguntas subjetivas.

Onde está a subjetividade dessa pergunta?

E se for subjetiva, o que faz ela ser uma subjetiva ruim? (pergunta retórica).

Comment: Realmente da para responder, ainda sim meu medo são as terríveis respostas que podem vir a surgir, mas no geral a resposta que existe parece boa, seria legal aproveitar um Wiki de Tag. Poderia ter uma semana de brindes com Wiki de Tags, tipo os que melhores e mais editarem ganharem camisetas kkkkkkkk xD

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que precisamos rever esse negócio de "medo que venha coisas ruins". Vou pensar em algo porque eu acho que dá para administrar isso de forma diferente e ampliar nosso potencial de ajuda sem prejudicar a qualidade do site.

Comment: Eu não tenho medo de "coisas ruins", eu tenho medo dos "upvotes free" que coisas de baixa qualidade ganham, dando a impressão que uma resposta ruim é o caminho ideal ou é a correta. Como isso é rotina eu sempre fico com o pé atrás com certos tipos de perguntas.

Comment: Se essa for liberada, então outras inúmeras que foram fechadas pra traz, com este mesmo tipo de questionamento, deveriam ser reabertas então, pois toda vez que alguém pergunta "onde ou como aprender/iniciar linguagem x", a pergunta é fechada como fora do escopo ou baseada em opiniões.

Comment: Uma [simples pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=aprender+is%3Aquestion) mostra isso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então vamos pensar em algo que possa solucionar isso inequivocamente. Eu tenho a impressão que respostas sem qualidade ocorrem mais em respostas que normalmente não há dúvida que a pergunta deva ficar aberta. Me parece que essas perguntas que podem vir algo ruim costumam vir mais "não respostas" do que baixa qualidade. Estou observando e acho que estamos focando no problema errado e como consequência disto estamos criando problemas para coisas boas. Claro que tudo precisa ser visto caso a caso.

Comment: @diegofm esta não está pedindo uma lista de material para estudar, está pedindo algo canônico.

Comment: Queria eu acreditar que com uma ou duas orientações esses usuários parassem de Ctrl+C pra qualquer coisa na sede de responder algo, mas não vai acontecer :/

Comment: @bigown é a tal debate que eu tenho sempre contigo, as perguntas que atraem más respostas não são boas para o site... A tua resposta é boa, mas acaba por ser também «veja aqui», «veja ali», só que com fontes oficias. Acho que esse exemplo acaba por ser [uma pergunta de lista](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/819/7210) «disfarçada» com um bom texto e uma boa lista.

Comment: @bigown mas atrai respostas que vão acabar apontando apenas para links ou opiniões baseadas no aprendizado de quem respondeu. A sua resposta mesmo, apesar de bem elaborada, apontou para diversos links de documentação.

Comment: o @diegofm explicou melhor que eu ^^^

Comment: @JorgeB. como um lista pode ter apenas uma resposta possível? Vocês parecem não ter lido a pergunta, não estão "respondendo" o que foi perguntado, estão apenas justificando que a pergunta é ruim para o site, e estão ignorando o fato que não pode cada um dizer o que bem entende, só uma resposta é possível. A resposta para esta pergunta é útil para muita gente e não depende de opinião. Ter *link* em respostas **nunca** foi um problema. Ter só o *link* é problema, mesmo assim depende de contexto. Ninguém disse porque essa pergunta é baseada em opinião.

Comment: @bigown «Onde devo aprender classes e métodos?» Só uma resposta é possível? Tu dizes que é nas fontes oficiais, mas eu posso responder que ele pode aprender classes e métodos no site http://w3schools.com de uma forma mais simples. (site que eu pessoalmente não gosto) e seria uma resposta válida como as outras. Outro pode dizer que pode aprender em site x ou y ou no livro z. Eu não disse que não é útil para as pessoas, as perguntas de listas são úteis, mas devem estar no site? Isso já é outra pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB. aí qualquer pergunta deveria ser fechada porque em toda pergunta alguém pode dar só um *link*, qualquer pergunta feita pode receber uma resposta que fala alguma bobagem. A ideia do fechamento não é impedir que respostas ruins sejam postadas, até porque isso só aconteceria se tudo fosse fechado. A ideia é **impedir que seja respondida sem que possa gerar uma resposta boa**. Acho que há um entendimento errado de sempre a mesma meia dúzia do porquê fechar. O problema das listas é outro e esta pergunta não pede uma lista. Se a pessoa postar algo que ñ foi perguntado é problema da resposta

Comment: @bigown ora veja "principalmente baseada em opiniões - Várias perguntas boas geram algum grau de opinião com base na experiência de especialistas, mas as respostas a esta pergunta **tenderão** a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões e não em fatos, referências ou experiência específica."

Comment: É o caso, como de costume, desta pergunta, as respostas vão tender a ser quase completamente baseadas na opinião pessoal. A sua é de que as fontes oficiais são as melhores para aprender, eu posso achar que não são. E não estou errado, para mim pode ser mais fácil de aprender no site x que é especializado em Android.

Comment: A problemática das listas é outra, mas o ênfase é o mesmo, há uma tendência para gerar más respostas. Então não as queremos no site.

Comment: A resposta é totalmente baseada em fato, não tem nada de opinião. A não ser que considere qualquer coisa postada no site uma opinião, o que até é. Postar um código que resolve um problema de alguém tem mais opinião que isto. Tem dezenas, centenas, milhares, ou até milhões de formas diferentes de fazer a mesma coisa. Boa parte delas serão ruins. Uma parcela ainda será defendida por alguns. Vocês estão culpando a pergunta por uma possível inexistente resposta ruim. Ninguém perguntou qual é a melhor. Ninguém pediu lista.

Comment: Lembra [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43105/refer%C3%AAncias-para-aprendizado-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web), bigown? É um caso muito parecido, certo? Entendo que o tratamento tenha de ser uniforme em ambos os casos (seja fechando ou mantendo aberta).

Comment: @bigown Claro que todas as perguntas são baseadas em alguma opinião, mas há umas mais que outras que tendem a ter respostas piores. Se eu perguntar «Onde eu devo aprender sobre MD5?» ou «Onde devo aprender sobre SHA-1?», sabes-me responder? Achas que são perguntas para o site?

Comment: @bfavaretto essa é claramente ampla, talvez até fora de escopo, mas não é baseada em opinião. É mais um fechamento errado, ainda que deva ser fechada mesmo. Tem trocentas perguntas no site que pede documentação, ou a resposta deve remeter à documentação. Isso não é opinião. Que bom que tem pessoas concordando com o que você comentou agora, imagino que sejam as mesmas pessoas que estão concordando que dava dar o mesmo tratamento, então vamos consertar o erro lá e evitar o erro nessa nova que eu respondi. Se alguém achasse outro motivo pra fechar, talvez tivesse razão, opinião não é.

Comment: Concordo que é ampla.

Comment: @JorgeB. se tiver uma resposta canônica é tranquilo. O problema é se não tiver. O problema todo é esse. Nessa pergunta que está em debate a pessoa não sabe qual é o processo de achar a informação e nós podemos ajudar canonicamente. Ele não está pedindo materiais de estudo, ele quer saber o que ele faz nessa situação, este é o foco da pergunta. O *link* foi um bônus, ele sequer dizer que quer saber sobre o PDF, sobre o Android. Essa é uma das melhores perguntas básicas postadas no site, ainda que não esteja lá muito bem escrita (melhorei um pouco, mas dá pra melhorar mais).

Comment: @bigown todas elas têm respostas canónicas. Se perguntassem «Onde posso aprender sobre nsis?» e se alguém respondesse que tem a documentação em http://nsis.sourceforge.net. Seria a resposta canónica? Mesmo sendo a documentação uma desgraça? Falo por experiência própria neste caso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, mas se fosse só isso, seria *link only*, ou seja, não é uma resposta. Se a pergunta só quer saber onde é a documentação, tem esse problema na pergunta. A pergunta não estava pedindo um link, eu coloquei pra deixar mais útil, se tirar o link minha resposta continua valendo, só será menos útil, falta um exemplo. Se uma documentação é ruim, vc deve olhar onde? Tem lugar bom? Talvez a resposta canônica seja que não tem nada que dê para usar. Não tem *link*, e aí aí tá ok? Se a resposta é objetiva, é ok. Existir a razão de fechamento "baseado em opinião" é evitar discussões e tolices.

Comment: @bigown então mas a sua resposta canónica é canónica para você, para outros pode não ser. Por isso é que eu não gosto nada dessa palavra, «canónica». Mas o que está em causa não é isso. Porque, como você disse e bem, todas elas acabam por ser baseadas em opinião. A diferença está em (e passo a citar) *mas as respostas a esta pergunta **tenderão** a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões e não em fatos*, não quer dizer que sejam todas, apenas tendem a isso. Deixe ficar uma pergunta dessas aberta e verá.

Comment: Todas as respostas são canônicas para a pessoa. Na verdade várias perguntas assim têm ficado abertas aos montes e nada de ruim acontece. Eu pago pra ver. Se acontecer tudo isso que você acha quem vai ter um trabalhão sou eu. Falo isso porque em casos assim não acontecem problemas. Não estou dizendo que em tudo não vai acontecer, depende do caso, esse é um que não vai acontecer grandes problemas. Se alguém responder algo que acha que as pessoas farão provavelmente não será um resposta válida.

Comment: Algumas leituras podem ajudar: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1338/101, https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3738/101, https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/692/101, https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/732/101.

Answer (score 18):

> Bom, irei explicar o motivo de meu voto, mas caso entenda que seja passível de respostas, ficarei feliz em retirar o mesmo.

Primeiro, vamos separar a pergunta em partes:

#### 1º Como eu aprendo sobre classes e métodos?

Cada um pode aprender de formas diferentes, em lugares diferentes. Porém, não é bem isso que me levou a votar, e sim que isso pode ser muito amplo.

Seria melhor aproveitado se a pessoa possuísse algumas dúvidas mas diretas, ou seja, ela leu sobre classes e métodos em algum local e teve dúvidas. Essas dúvidas seriam muito bem aceitas.

#### 2º Por exemplo: se eu precisar exibir um PDF, como vou aprender a fazer isso?

Sinceramente, esta pergunta está muito ampla. O que exatamente é desejável aprender?

#### 3º Tem alguma coisa em algum lugar para estudar, ou vou ter que perguntar a alguém?

Lugar para estudar existem vários. Temos livros, sites, artigos, revistas e sim, perguntar para *alguém* é de grande ajuda também. Todavia, acho que teríamos várias respostas baseadas em opiniões para este item.

Devemos ter em conta que apesar de ser o melhor local, uma pessoa que está começando agora nem sempre consegue entender o site oficial de uma tecnologia/linguagem.

#### Conclusão

Baseado nas perguntas contidas, nada impede que alguém coloque qualquer link para tutorial e fale que **aquele tutorial é bom** e tal.

A sua resposta está com links oficiais das tags [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) e [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), o que é ótimo. Todavia, alguém também pode falar que lá não é um bom lugar para começar a aprender e no site X seria melhor. Isso seria uma opinião da pessoa, não podemos falar que ela está certa ou errada, pois ela realmente pode ter achada o site X melhor.

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: "pode" é diferente de "será". Pode é o problema da resposta, não da pergunta. A dúvida direta da pessoa é onde pode aprender. Ela não quer tutorial, livro, curso, quer saber onde tem uma informação canônica. A segunda pergunta é retórica, ele não quer saber isso, ele usou aquilo pra mostrar melhor a dúvida dele, o que aparentemente muita gente não entendeu. Mesmo que tenha vários lugares pra estudar, serão materiais de referência, ou será a documentação ou baseada nela.

Comment: É diferente da pessoa criar um material próprio que pode ter qualidade ou não. É possível uma resposta que não seja baseada em opinião? Se for opinião, ela falha nos 6 itens constantes em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101. "Devemos ter em conta que apesar de ser o melhor local, uma pessoa que está começando agora nem sempre consegue entender o site oficial de uma tecnologia/linguagem." isso é problema dela, a resposta canônica não tem nada a ver com o fato da pessoa não saber aproveitá-la.

Comment: Nenhuma pergunta impede que a pessoa coloque um *link* para um tutorial e ele pode ser ruim. O problema é quando a pergunta só quer isso, o problema é que todas respostas possível sejam um tutorial que não se sabe se tem qualidade. Esse caso não pede isto. Qualquer resposta dada no site pode ir alguém lá e falar que aquilo não é bom e não deveria fazer assim. O que faria todas perguntas serem baseadas em opinião.

Comment: @bigown então se eu fizer a pergunta «Onde devo aprender classes e métodos?» ok, se for «Há algum site/tutorial onde posso aprender classes e métodos» notok? Então é só ir editar as perguntas todas até agora sobre o assunto e apagar a parte do tutorial e já não são baseadas em opinião?

Comment: *[...]Ela não quer tutorial, livro, curso, quer saber onde tem uma informação canônica[...]* Não tem como afirmar isso. Livro, tutorial, curso, tudo pode ser um local para aprender, que é exatamente o que o AP quer. Se olharmos a sua própria resposta, os links que você colocou. Você **acha** que são bons lugares para aprender? Ninguém pode discordar disso, mas se eu virar e falar que também existe o site X e o livro Y que tem as os mesmos autores ou não dos links que você postou? Como podemos falar que está errada está resposta, mesmo você discordando dos links ali apresentados?

Comment: A pessoa pode responder de uma forma subjetiva e com links ruins. Porém, quem pode afirmar que ela não aprendeu por esses links?

Comment: @Randrade mas eu até posso achar que os links que ele pós não são bons para aprender. A documentação das linguagens nem sempre é a melhor, já vi casos que sites pessoais são melhores que a documentação oficial.

Comment: E a melhor resposta possível poderia ser apenas: "Aqui mesmo, [elabore uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) perguntando o que são classes e métodos". Quem poderia dizer que esta resposta é inválida? Ou até mesmo uma resposta com [a busca pré definida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classes) poderia ser válido, pois alguém poderia ter aprendido desta forma.

Comment: @JorgeB. Então, entra justamente no opinativo. Você, e diversas pessoas podem falar isso (dependendo da documentação eu também, mas queria não ser opinativo aqui, rsrs) e não temos como falar que está certo ou errado.

Comment: @JorgeB. você está começando entender o site. Editar uma pergunta para que ela permaneça aberta ou possa ser reaberta é um dos pilares do site. Se alguém fizer isso é o melhor que podemos ter. Inclusive pedidos de tutoriais são fechadas como fora de escopo e não baseada em opinião. São perguntas que não tem um problema específico. De qualquer forma não existem esses tutoriais, existem guias de referência, que são canônicos. Tutoriais são pra outra coisa, esses são problemáticos.

Comment: @Randrade tudo isso vale pra qualquer pergunta no site. Ela pode aprender com respostas ruins aqui, e algumas muito votadas. Vocês não estão entendendo o que é baseado em opinião. Você acham que aqui a Wikipedia que não pode ter nada de opinião (e tem muita lá). Opinião é inerente a quase tudo. Quase todos os códigos postados aqui não fundamentam porque deve ser daquele jeito, então é tudo opinião. Tudo tem mais de uma forma de fazer, cada um coloca a que acham melhor, é opinião? Ok, então sai fechando tudo. Mandar perguntar em algum lugar é uma resposta muito inválida, até comentário não cabe

Comment: @bigown Em resumo, eu apenas acho que se a pergunta fosse **O que são classes e métodos?** seria válida (dependendo da forma perguntada) e **Onde devo aprender classes e métodos?** não. Você está em um site que onde você aprende as coisas. Perguntar aqui onde se deve aprender geram respostas opinativas.

Comment: É possível dizer que consultar a documentação é errado? Se não é possível, então é possível dizer que é o certo, porque ou é certo ou é errado. Se é possível, ótimo que diga que está errado. Isto é o oposto de ser baseado em opinião. Isto é diferente de "não tem como saber se é certo ou errado". Você pode não gostar, você pode achar que está melhor servido de outra forma, mas não pode dizer que é errado consultar a documentação. É certo fazer isso, mesmo que exista outra forma melhor. Ser melhor não está em questão. Dá para dizer se é certo ou errado, não depende de opinião, é canônico.

Comment: @bigown eu bem sei como funciona o site, há perguntas que dá para melhorar, há outras que por melhores que se ponham continuam fora do âmbito do site.

Comment: @bigown mas vendo por esse lado de que não tem de saber se é certo ou errado, ai já vem as respostas de listas, eu posso chegar ali e responder uma lista infinita de sítios, melhores ou piores onde ele pode aprender sobre o assunto. Onde pode? Eu posso citar um sem número de sítios onde pode aprender, fazendo uma lista.

Comment: @bigown Eu não posso falar que a documentação é errada (a de PHP em PT já me mostraram erro, mas não vem ao caso xD). Porém, o fato de consultar a documentação ser algo correto, não significa que lá é o **melhor** lugar para aprender. Raramente uma documentação pensa no leigo, e muitas delas são confusas. Note que a pergunta é " Onde devo aprender", e se a pessoa não sabe de nada, não é possível afirmar que a pessoa irá ou não aprender na documentação, assim como em nenhum outro lugar. Se a pergunta fosse "O que é isso ou aquilo" eu acho que é diferente do que "onde aprender isso ou aquilo".

Comment: Não há pedido de melhor., não há pedido de lista. A pergunta é canônica. Vocês estão ignorando isso. Eu concordaria se não fosse canônica.

Answer (score 9):

A minha resposta à tua pergunta será pegar na tua resposta e substituir 2 coisas (a negrito). Será a minha resposta válida? Será que vão aparecer muitas mais como a minha?

> Tudo o que pode usar está documentado. Pelo menos em bibliotecas que
> valem a pena usar. Todo informação básica do uso das classes está lá.
>
> O [**Android Central**](http://forums.androidcentral.com/) tem um site dedicado a isto. Tem que saber usar muito bem
> este site.  Tem que ter uma boa noção da sua organização, o que tem lá
> no geral, saber achar o que precisa ali. Tem que decorar o que usa
> mais e saber o que pode ser útil.
>
> **Tem também a documentação no site [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) que também é de grande ajuda e você ainda pode testar as funções com exemplos
> online.**

---

Daqui para baixo dá para todas as perguntas de «Onde devo aprender X»?

> Tem que aprender ler a documentação com cuidado, entender as minúcias.
> E precisa saber que nem tudo o que precisa saber sobre o uso daquela
> classe está escrito na documentação. Usar bem depende de experiência.
> Cada dia que usar bem, passará usar melhor no dia seguinte.
>
> É possível encontrar outras documentação. O próprio Stack Overflow tem
> um site só de documentações diversas. Não sabe inglês? Terá
> dificuldade de desenvolver software em alto nível.
>
> Procure outras fontes, confronte o que leu em algum lugar. Não aceite
> a primeira informação que recebe como uma verdade absoluta. Tenha uma
> atitude crítica e tenha certeza que entende todos fundamentos da
> computação para conseguir fazer isso com qualidade.
>
> Na dúvida pergunte para quem é mais experiente.

*Nota: A e se for para dizer todos os «onde» passa a ser o [problema das listas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/819/7210).*

Comment: Atenção que os exemplos foram só para servir de isso mesmo, exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado por confirmar que dá para responder canonicamente :) A pergunta nunca foi sobre onde, um local específico, isso que vocês ainda não entenderam.

Comment: @bigown mas ninguém está a dizer que não dá, só que dá para ter milhares de respostas canónicas, e muitas delas vão ser más, porque o que vai importar ao AP não é o seu texto de COMO ele deve aprender, mas sim ONDE ele pode aprender. Ou eu percebi mal a pergunta? Pelos comentários do AP aqui parece-me que não.

Comment: @bigown "Tem alguma coisa em algum lugar para estudar" tem sim aqui, aqui e aqui.

Comment: Obrigado por confirmar mais uma vez o que eu estou dizendo. Uma resposta canônica não pode ser baseada em opinião, a não ser que considere como opinião um dogma estabelecido. 1 + 1 = 2 é um fato canônico que foi gerado pela opinião de alguém, não é um fato inexorável a não ser que adote o dogma matemático vigente.

Comment: @bigown mas você acha que a sua resposta é 2? Porque raio é que não é a minha que é 2? A única coisa que muda na minha, quase, é o onde e não o como. Porque o ONDE é que que gera a opinião e não o COMO. E mesmo o como, apesar do seu como ser bom, eu posso dar também outro como que seja pelo menos tão correto como o seu. É por isso que não gosto dessa palavra. Até porque 1+1 pode ser 4, se a premissa for que 1=2. ;)

Comment: Vou falar pela última vez: **todas respostas são assim**.

Comment: @bigown não são, o que difere a minha resposta da tua é pura opinião. Eu não quero respostas como a minha no site, o conteúdo que realmente interessa é fruto só de opinião pessoal. Porque eu acabei pondo os sites que eu gosto.

Comment: Hipoteticamente, não usem o w3school já agora ;)

Answer (score 9):

Passei a última hora lendo essa discussão e tendo lembranças de 2 coisas que não aprecio muito:

1. Aqueles tópicos *intermináveis* de fóruns, onde cada post é um conjunto de citações de um post anterior com alguma resposta associada. Que invariavelmente giravam em torno de algum desentendimento semântico bem irrelevante. E que eu *adorava* participar.
2. Diagrama de Atividades (e UML em geral). Vocês não fazem ideia do quanto eu detesto UML.

Particularmente, acho que toda semântica possível e imaginável em torno dessa pergunta já foi discutida: desde as melhores palavras para se remover, ou trocar, de maneira a adequá-la ao site, até à quantidade de respostas que ela deve ter, e a quantidade de links em cada resposta. Minha experiência com qualquer discussão é que à medida em que as diferenças semânticas se constringem, maior é o indicativo de que ela deixou de ser produtiva.

> > > > > Tá certo
> > > >
> > > > Tá errado
> > >
> > > Tá **certo**
> >
> > Tá **errado**
>
> TÁ CERTO

<sup>Fig 1: Uma discussão que definitivamente tem futuro</sup>

Discutir interpretação de regras é importante, mas não se percam dentro do dicionário. As regras do SO são mantidas vagas pra tentar coibir esse tipo de comportamento, mas pode tranquilamente ter o efeito contrário se vocês não se policiarem.

O que me leva àquele segundo ponto, pelo qual eu nutro um ódio nada saudável...

Segundo [esse site](http://www.ateomomento.com.br/uml-diagrama-de-atividades/):

> O diagrama de atividades ilustra graficamente como será o funcionamento do software (em nível micro ou macro), como será a execução de alguma de suas partes, como será a atuação do sistema na realidade de negócio na qual ele está inserido.

O motivo de eu desgostar tanto de UML e seus diagramas é que pouca coisa me dá mais raiva que ter que *traçar um plano que eu tenho certeza absoluta que vai falhar*. De que adianta sentar, fazer um monte de diagrama lindo, e nos primeiros 15 minutos programando você percebe que tem um caso que não estava previsto... E agora seu diagrama está um pouco mais complicado.

E isso se repete mais mil vezes, até seu diagrama ser uma bagunça completa e ter tanta utilidade na tomada de decisão quanto um papel de bala com seu horóscopo do dia.

**Não façam isso com as regras do site.**

[image: Bem-vindo ao SOpt! Eu serei o seu guia]
<sup>Fig 2: Bem vindo ao SOpt! Esse é o guia rápido de como perguntar</sup>

Muitas vezes no chat eu sou perguntado sobre o que fazer com alguns casos, ou minha interpretação de alguma regra, e minha resposta sempre é a mais honesta o possível e quase sempre termina com "mas **pense** antes", ou "tenha calma".

Praticamente tudo na nossa plataforma foi feito de maneira a ser revisado e desfeito se necessário. Tudo é feito sob a premissa de que vocês vão avaliar com a mente quieta, a espinha ereta e o coração tranquilo. Não é necessário pressa, não é necessário tomar uma decisão final sobre tudo com base na primeira impressão.

Não é necessário fazer um definição ultra-complexa de quais palavras, formatos, e significados cada pergunta deve ter; Qual o valor "adequado" de votos que uma pergunta ou resposta deve ter; Do número e qualidade ideal de respostas que uma pergunta deve atrair; Quanto mais propenso a definir esses valores *de antemão*, mais improdutivas e frustrantes (e frequentes) as conversas sobre as regras vão ser. **A ordem é um convite inacreditavelmente sedutor à entropia**.

## Rendimentos Decrescentes

Existe uma [teoria](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lei_dos_rendimentos_decrescentes) em economia sobre o ponto em que o aumento em ganho não justifica mais o aumento em trabalho. Se você é do Brasil, pode conhecer também como o famoso "excesso de preciosismo."

Na dúvida, prefiram **sempre** deixar algo passar pelas gretas a ter que criar uma regra nova, tentar aplicá-la retroativamente, e permanecer eternamente vigilantes para o próximo caso em que ela precisar ser aplicada. Isso só adiciona piora a curva de aprendizado para quem chega, aumenta o trabalho para quem já está aqui e - pela lei de rendimentos decrescentes - tende a eventualmente não apresentar o retorno que seria esperado.

Não apliquem as instruções do site ao pé da letra, sem avaliar contexto, ou sem tentar entender se aquele caso é realmente é um problema. O SOpt *ainda pode se dar a esse luxo*. Vocês não precisam temer - a custo da sua sanidade - uma enxurrada de coisas ruins aparecendo no site de uma hora para a outra. Claro que sempre vão existir perguntas a serem fechadas, e usuários causando problemas... Mas isso é parte do SO.

**Não há nada** que possa ser feito para evitar todos os problemas que acontecem e vão acontecer no SOpt. Nada. Zero. Se você ainda tem essa esperança... sinto ser a pobre alma que te avisou. As filas sempre vão ser necessárias. Os sinalizadores também. Os moderadores também. O Meta também. Agir como se fosse possível "fazer algo agora para prevenir o caos no futuro", especialmente no que diz respeito ao tratamento de perguntas em cima da linha entre o que é ou não permitido<sup>1</sup>, é como querer proteger um belo jardim construindo um muro de 5 metros ao redor dele.

Pode até ser efetivo, mas não faz muito sentido.

Um jardim - principalmente um jardim essencialmente comunitário como o nosso - definitivamente precisa de vigias. Mas ele precisa, principalmente, de jardineiros. De quem cultive e mantenha o terreno fértil, e dê cursos de jardinagem.

Sejam jardineiros.

---

<sup>1.</sup> A pergunta é tão limítrofe que haviam discussões sobre que palavras deveriam ser alteradas, ou removidas, para torná-la mais aceitável.

Comment: Concordo com tudo. E como moderador tenho percebido isso ainda mais. Curiosamente alguns dos desafios que encontro aqui eu não encontrava do Programmers. Se não me engano o bfavaretto falou publicamente que muda muito a percepção qdo se é moderador. E é verdade. Eu quero fazer um post pra debater essa questão e ver se dá pra avançar um pouco.

Comment: Também concordo, a discussão não estava a levar a lado nenhum. Era mais fácil perguntar se acham que a pergunta devia estar no site.

Comment: A tua resposta fez-me lembrar o celebre caso dos votos serem usados aqui como *likes* do facebook, eu avisei aqui, ninguém quis saber, mas é o que acontece, infelizmente. Se calhar  é como tu dizes, não dá para fazer nada, mais vale aceitar e pronto. É por isso que eu cada vez menos venho ao site. Eu entrei numa altura em que me ensinaram a perguntar, eu fiz uma pergunta de fraca qualidade e foi fechada, vim pro meta e fui elucidado. Aprendi com tudo isso...

Comment: @JorgeB. Pra ser sincero, me parece que você interpretou algo diferente do que eu quis passar. Eu quis dizer justamente para não se preocuparem com coisas como "upvotes como likes" (pela lei de rendimentos decrescentes). E que não é uma questão de "aceitar e ponto, não vale a pena mais vir ao site ou ajudá-lo" e sim entender quais as melhores maneiras de ajudar o site, que não acabem mais atrapalhando que ajudando. De boas intenções, o inferno, o Meta, as filas e os sinalizadores, estão cheios...

Comment: @Gabe também não foi isso que eu disse, mas deixa para lá, não vamos chegar a lado nenhum com essa conversa.

Comment: Não sei se eu que não estou conseguindo interpretar o texto, mas resumindo, é à favor ou contra a pergunta em sua forma inicial?

Comment: @Randrade Resumindo? A favor

Comment: Eu concordo que o pessoal está perdendo muito tempo com preciosismo. Mas, na minha opinião, não é o tipo de pergunta que deveria estar no SOpt. Então preciso discordar. Talvez eu tenha usado muito o SOen... sei lá...

Comment: @EMBarbosa usar muito ou pouco o SOen não influencia muita coisa na opinião sobre o SOpt. A maioria das pessoas aqui nesse tópico não é ativo por lá, por exemplo. Eu tenho conta no SOen, e ajudo a moderá-lo, e ainda assim acho que essa pergunta é mais valiosa ao SOpt do que o esforço de removê-la de maneira "bem definida" jamais seria

Comment: @Gabe, não sei se meu comentário passou outra impressão, mas não quis dizer que o esforço está além do necessário. Concordei com a perda de tempo com o preciosismo. O que quis dizer quando falei sobre o uso do SOen é que essa pergunta não seria aceitável por lá e *eu* **acho** isso bom. Mas sabemos que aqui não é o SOen. (:

Comment: @EMBarbosa Eu entendi seu comentário. Mas não acho que me fiz entender... O excesso de preciosismo em torno dessa pergunta não é só aqui no Meta. Essa discussão é um sintoma, não uma doença. O preciosismo está no julgamento em fechá-la. E que passar muito ou pouco tempo no SOen não tem nada a ver com decidir a favor ou contra o fechamento. Eu posso conversar com o Shog ou o Tim Post sobre a nossa pergunta e tenho uma forte suspeita de que eles concordariam com a reabertura - mesmo sendo mitos do SOen.

Comment: "A ordem é um convite inacreditavelmente sedutor à entropia.". @Gabe, isso foi sensacional! :-)

Answer (score 5):

O problema está **na quantidade de opiniões que uma pergunta pode gerar** - ela teria que ser *sanitized* para ficar própria para o site.

Eu tentei responder a pergunta (logo abaixo), removendo minhas opiniões, o que é um exercício interessante.

---

*Mas minha opinião é que se é necessário um "esforço" para poder responder uma pergunta sem dar opiniões, esse esforço deve ser direcionado à edição da própria pergunta, para que ela não "fomente" respostas do mesmo tipo.*

Ou seja, não é porque você consegue responder bem e objetivamente uma pergunta ruim e subjetiva, que o resto da comunidade também irá conseguir.

---

Aí vai:

> Como eu aprendo sobre classes e métodos em geral? Tem algum lugar onde tem informações sobre isso?

*<s>Como **você** aprende eu não sei. Muitas pessoas tem facilidade em ler a documentação - eu só fui aprender alguma coisa fazendo um curso.</s>*

Sim, para a linguagem Java tem o [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). Para o Android, tem a página de referência no [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

> Por exemplo: se eu precisar exibir um PDF, como vou aprender a fazer isso?

<s>*Aí complica.*</s>

Em Java, <s>provavelmente</s> não será possível ler um PDF com a biblioteca padrão, ou seja, terá que usar uma escrita por terceiros, e essa normalmente terá sua própria documentação. <s>Essa é uma boa pergunta pra você fazer no [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)!</s> No Android, pesquisando no Android Developers [você encontra uma classe que lida com arquivos .PDF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/package-summary.html)

> Tem alguma coisa em algum lugar para estudar, ou vou ter que perguntar a alguém? Nem estou preocupado com o lugar específico, mas quero entender qual é a forma de eu obter essas informações que preciso para fazer uma atividade específica de uma aplicação.

<s>*Eu fiz um curso, foi a única coisa que me ajudou. Você pode perguntar para o [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), ele sabe de virtualmente tudo. Você pode perguntar no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) também, o pessoal sempre ajuda.*</s>

As informações estão em todos os lugares - a documentação oficial é supostamente a mais correta/atual, <s>e é onde os melhores programadores fazem suas pesquisas</s>.

<s>Eu gosto de procurar no [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), mas tem vários outros sites também que eu não poderei listar aqui, basta procurar no Google. Mas ainda acho que você deveria estudar pelo manual - eu aprendi a dirigir o meu carro assim.</s>

Comment: Toda pergunta pode ser respondida com opinião, nem toda pergunta exige opinião, essa é a questão.

Answer (score 3):

A questão é a seguinte. Minha pergunta precisava de uma resposta e não de uma opinião, onde nem o Google conseguiu me responder direito, e ninguém em outro local. Então eu fiz a pergunta sobre como aprender um código, e me deram a documentação. Essa documentação é muito complexa, mas só la vou aprender sobre o que perguntei aqui. Então a resposta não é valida? Claro que é valida, me deu a solução, e não uma opinião se eu poderia aceitar ou não. Se este local é pra aprendermos sobre (como fazer) então a resposta é valida.

Comment: Eu não achei sua pergunta baseada em opiniões. A questão lá é o "como", e existe muitas formas de "como fazer". Vc não procurou qual é a "melhor" forma de aprender, isso esta claro na pergunta. Mas ela poderia ser fechada como ampla demais ou fora de escopo.

Comment: Existem muitas formas? Me dê pelo menos duas:

Comment: Falei hipoteticamente no sentido de que existe muitas formas de como aprender sobre classes e métodos.

Comment: Forma de aprender, hum, vc pode ver videos no youtube, ou fazer perguntas aqui no SOpt, ou usar aplicativos para aprender sobre programação. As perguntas tem que ser baseada em um problema real ou relacionadas a algum termo. Da uma olhada no [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: A comunidade é de gente que sabe é quer ensinar e ajudar certo? Então vocês só sabem digitar código aqui? Eu preciso necessariamente ser um profissional para entrar aqui? Ou eu não posso perguntar como eu posso conhecer novos recursos?

Comment: A questão é: em nenhum outro local eu tive respostas, e minha pesquisa foi longa.

Comment: As perguntas tem que ser no minimo objetivas e reproduzíveis. Vc fez quatro perguntas (o titulo questiona onde aprender) e as perguntas são amplas de mais.

Comment: @Adlem Você pode, por exemplo, aprender isso aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/145/object-class-methods-and-constructor

Comment: @JorgeB. Pronto, percebeu como sua resposta foi útil? Foi baseada em opiniões? não.

Comment: @AdlemElvis se eu dei só esse site, é sim. Porque é que eu não dei outros sites? Ou livros? Ou seja o que for? Se você quer uma resposta de todos os sítios, já entra numa resposta de listas que mencionei acima nos comentários da pergunta.

Comment: Se você me indicasse vários links, livros, sites, ainda não seria opiniões, seriam sugestões. Sugestão é uma palavra com significado diferente de opinião.

Comment: Se você me indicasse vários links, livros, sites, ainda não seria opiniões, seriam sugestões. Sugestão é uma palavra com significado diferente de opinião.

Comment: @AdlemElvis se for todos ou quase todos é o velho problema das listas de documentação de aprendizagem que não são permitidos no site, pelo menos por enquanto. Se não for, e for para dizer um ou dois, cada um vai dizer o que gosta mais para aprender. Numa das duas situações encaixa.

Comment: @AdlemElvis concordo com tudo o que disse, o único problema é que sugestão e opinião não são antagônicas, pode ter uma sugestão objetiva e uma sugestão só opinativa. "Me dê uma livro aí sobre assunto tal?" É ampla, só dá para responder baseado em opinião, mas antes de ser baseada em opinião, não tem um foco, qualquer resposta pode ser certa. "Qual livro oficial tem todas instruções do x86?" tem foco e é canônica, não tem opinião. Você pode até sugerir mais de um livro, mas qq resposta válida deverá ter o que foi perguntado.

Comment: @bigown você acha que faz sentido termos perguntas «Qual o livro que tem todas as instruções do x86?» no site?

Comment: @JorgeB. totalmente. Isso nunca foi colocado fora de questão no site, a resposta é canônica. Vocês resolveram agora que se existe uma resposta canônica, mas pode ter outras que não são então a pergunta é ruim, o que inviabiliza todas perguntas.

Comment: Acho que eu não entendi muito bem esse site. O site é pra quem sabe classes e métodos ou também é util pra quem quer aprender sobre classes e métodos? Também é útil pra quem quer aprender sobre classes e métodos? E se for útil pra quem quer aprender sobre classes e métodos, como minha pergunta deveria ser feita então?

Comment: @AdlemElvis Apenas uma dúvida. Se ao invés de você falar "Onde devo aprender..." você colocasse "Qual a diferença entre..."? Desta forma você teria respostas objetivas, e tenho certeza que as boas respostas teriam links de referências para se aprofundar no assunto. Pense em alguém que tenha a mesma dúvida que você. Se ela entrar no site já tiver essa dúvida sanada aqui, seria melhor do que ela ir para outro lugar.

Comment: Eu disse " Onde aprender..." por quê não é uma pergunta especifica, por exemplo, se eu perguntasse: como se utiliza a classe MediaPlayer, alguém iria responder como. Mas a minha pergunta é: onde eu devo aprender sobre as classes, pois eu não quero aprender sobre só uma, eu quero aprender sobre todas que eu possa precisar, por exemplo, como exibir um PDF. A resposta foi " Documentação ", não foi a melhor resposta? se não foi, eu não sei, mas que foi útil, isso é verdade.

Answer (score -1):

Acabei de reformular a pergunta:

O que é preciso para aprender classes e métodos específicos para uma tarefa?

Baseada no Tour do site:

Faça perguntas, obtenha respostas, sem distrações

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Então se a pergunta continuar sendo negativada, ela deverá continuar fechada, não por ser baseada em opiniões, e sim por outro motivo.

Comment: Não seria melhor editar a sua resposta já existente aqui com essa informação ao inves de criar uma nova resposta somente para isso?

Comment: @diegofm cada resposta tem uma intenção diferente. Esse é um novo ponto da discussão, essa pergunta faz parte de uma possível solução, onde todos os interessados poderiam discutir esse novo ponto. O que eu já escrevi em outras respostas, fazem parte de outro ponto da discussão, e esses pontos já passaram, os pontos falavam da antiga pergunta, agora a pergunta está diferente, então esse é um novo ponto.

Answer (score -2):

Achei que era óbvio a objetividade da pergunta. Ok, vamos considerar que ela é baseada em opinião, que as respostas seriam subjetivas. Só devemos fechar as subjetivas ruins. Vamos avaliar se ela é uma subjetiva ruim baseado em um [critério há muito estabelecido na rede](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101):

> Grandes questões subjetivas inspiram respostas que explicam o "porquê" e o "como".

Esta pergunta pede o como, ela deseja uma resposta que seja mais que um nome e um *link*.

> Grandes questões subjetivas tendem a ter respostas longas e não curtas.

A pergunta quer saber o que sobre um processo de aprendizado, não uma sugestão de onde aprender.

> Grandes questões subjetivas têm um tom construtivo, justo e imparcial.

Em nenhum momento a pergunta dá uma tendência para um lado específico.

> Grandes questões subjetivas convidam a partilha de experiências e não de opiniões.

A minha experiência e de qualquer desenvolvedor profissional é que a documentação deve ser o local primário a ser consultado para aprender sobre as classes de uma API. Tem gente que pode ter outra experiência, o que não quer dizer que seja só opinião. Se há uma fundamentação saímos da opinião boba e tendenciosa, para a experiência útil de alguém.

> Grandes questões subjetivas insistem que opiniões devem ser apoiadas por fatos e referências.

Na verdade a pergunta é tão objetiva que fica até difícil exigir alguma referência. Alguém pode ir lá e dizer "não consulte a documentação, ela não vai te ajudar aprender sobre as classes e métodos de uma API"?

> Grandes questões subjetivas são mais do que diversão social boba.

Acho que não há dúvidas que não está procurando um diversão boba ou só, saber o que as pessoas gostam.

## Conclusão

Tem gente que acha que é opinião se tiver a palavra "melhor" na pergunta. Isso pode dar um indício, mas não garante que seja realmente baseada em opinião. Essa sequer tem isso. Está havendo uma inferência que poderia vir um monte de *link* para algum lugar.

Ok, dava a impressão que pedia algum lugar? Eu editei e tirei isso. Eu acho que se havia uma interpretação que era opinativa, agora não há mais. Se há, me digam especificamente que eu vou lá e resolvo.

Comment: Pela resposta do OP [aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5967/20615) o link da documentação que ajudou a solucionar o problema, então ele esperava sim um link.
Ele também disse que não encontrou o que procurava, nem no Google. Dessa forma, ele buscava sim onde aprender.
Não entramos no teor do link ser a documentação, mas vamos lá. Como você disse, "qualquer desenvolvedor profissional" deve buscar a informação na documentação, o que eu concordo. Porém, o teor da pergunta não é de um "desenvolvedor profissional", se é que é possível julgar o que é "profissional" +.

Comment: Todas as pessoas que estão começando a desenvolver tem essa mesma dúvida. Se alguém não tem, é pq essa pessoa não sabe o que possui essa dúvida ainda.
Você disse um pouco sobre a documentação, então vamos falar diretamente da resposta e dos links agora. Se olharmos diretamente para os links da sua resposta, não achamaos nada sobre classes ou métodos (pelo menos eu não achei no link que você postou). É sabido também que grande parte das documentações são confusas, especialmente para quem está começando a aprender sobre programação. +

Comment: Se você pegar [este comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5965/uma-pergunta-que-pede-uma-informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-can%C3%B4nica-%C3%A9-opini%C3%A3o#comment22822_5967) do AP, podemos ver que a ideia da pergunta poderia ser outra, e com isso a pergunta poderia até mesmo ser fechada como ampla demais. Ou, se a pergunta fosse mais objetiva, poderia informar para o AP a diferença entre classes e que a ideologia de aprendizado dele pode estar certo ou errado (não posso entrar neste método). +

Comment: A pergunta foi fechada como opinativa na versão inicial, após as edições podem ser vista de outra forma. Independente da edição, eu ainda votaria para fechar. Poderia alterar o motivo de fechamento após a edição, mas ainda assim **eu** não acho que a pergunta é válida.

Comment: Não acho que a pergunta seja opinativa. Tenho no entanto dúvidas se ela está dentro do escopo do site - não a consigo enquadrar em nenhum dos itens enumerados em [Central de ajuda > Perguntando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @ramaral isso até é possível mesmo. Minha questão é sobre ser baseado em opinião. Acho que até há espaço pra discutir se estamos restringindo coisas demais que não causam problema algum, só porque está na regra.

Comment: @Randrade mesmo que o *link* seja útil, ainda assim ele é canônico. O comentário dele aqui só confirmou que que a pergunta não era sobre um item específico, era sobre como obter informações em geral de classes e métodos de uma API qualquer. Se você não achou no *link* que postei eu acho que você está procurando por outra coisa, o que indicaria que o entendimento do que é a pergunta está bem distante do que ele quer. Está claro o que ele quer. A gente vê o tempo todo que a maioria das pessoas não sabem nada sobre documentação, não entendem que é lá que tem tudo o que ela precisa. Eu disse isso.

Comment: Eu gostava de saber onde você retirou da pergunta que ele quer saber como aprender e não onde. Até os comentários dele aqui indicam que ele queria apenas saber onde. Eu até dei uma opção de link e ele concordou.

Comment: Você reformulou a pergunta para o que lhe dava jeito na resposta, não foi isso que eu vi que o AP queria. Mas fico-me por aqui.

Comment: Se a pergunta inicial fosse essa, e esse fosse a dúvida do AP claro que teria de estar no site. A diferença de ONDE para COMO é abismal. Você está levando a coisa para que encaixe na sua ideia, mas a verdade é que a pergunta não era com essa intenção. A intenção do AP era saber onde ele pode aprender.

Comment: @JorgeB. Neste caso não vejo grande diferença entre ONDE e COMO. Tanto que a resposta continua válida após a alteração.

Comment: @ramaral o problema não é a resposta atual, são as respostas más que pode gerar. Um "onde" para além de (segundo me parece) poder gerar respostas baseadas na opinião de cada um "eu aprendi aqui" pode também gerar respostas  do tipo link. "Pode aprender aqui, aqui, aqui. Como um "como" já tem de saber dizer alguma coisa mais... A resposta atual responde a "como" e indiretamente a um "onde", mas só indiretamente. Até podia não fazer referência ao local especifico...

Comment: @ramaral (cont) O que para mim faz uma grande diferença em termos de *«mas as respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões e não em fatos»*. Até agora ainda não consegui perceber isso doutra forma.

Comment: @JorgeB. Responder ONDE não é um questão de opinião, não no sentido de provocar discussão, que é a que a frase que citou se refere. Se a pergunta tem algum problema, no meu entendimento, é de escopo e não de "baseada em opiniões".

Comment: @ramaral então não é? Cada um vai acabar por dizer onde acha melhor pra aprender. Vai outro é diz, não não aqui é melhor. Isso não é criar discussão? É quase com "qual o melhor, Java ou c#".  "Onde", no meu entendimento, acaba por ser like "qual o melhor sítio", mas duma forma diferente. Pode também ser fora de âmbito do site, mas isso são outros quinhentos.

Comment: @ramaral este tipo de pergunta é à lá fórum no meu entendimento.

Comment: @JorgeB. bom ter entrado nesse ponto, 90% das perguntas do SOpt são a lá fórum, não tem nada mais fórum que o cara pedir para resolver o problema dele, não dar informações suficientes, precisar trocar trocentos comentários até saber o que ele quer, explicar cada detalhe porque o cara não sabe programar. Isso não é uma pergunta, é uma *thread* de fórum. É uma enorme discussão até chegar a algum lugar.

Comment: @bigown é por isso que eu acho que esse tipo de perguntas que você falou agora devam estar fechadas até o AP esclarecer o problema. se eu não vir o mínimo esforço é -1 e voto para fechar. Por isso é que eu tenho dito que o site anda nivelado por baixo.

Comment: @JorgeB. mas o problema é que a discussão vai rolar até ele conseguir o que quer, não vai fechar e ficar esperando ele arrumar. Mesmo que todo mundo ignore ele, o que vai acontecer é que quase todas perguntas serão fechadas e não respondidas. Você estão procurando uma idealização que não é possível.

Comment: @bigown se calhar se toda a gente agisse assim, de fazer uma única pergunta num comentário e votar para fechar se calhar as pessoas punham-se finas e começavam a melhorar as perguntas. Eu já fui chamado a atenção por fechar pergunta cedo de mais, mas se ela não for boa deve estar fechada antes que comecem a chover respostas más. Eu não acho que esteja a ser demasiado idealista. Até porque há utilizadores que fazem perguntas quase sempre muito boas. Acho que é melhor tentar melhorar do que abrir mais o âmbito para pior.

Comment: @JorgeB. Se  "Onde" é *like* "Qual o melhor sítio" então "Como" é *like* "Qual a melhor forma para" e assim grande parte das perguntas terão de ser fechadas como "baseadas em opinião". Note que eu não estou a defender aquele tipo de pergunta, apenas estou a dizer que não a considero como "baseada em opinião".

Comment: @ramaral ora ai está um ponto intrigante, tenho de pensar melhor nisso.

Comment: Achei curioso que deram negativo, mas ninguém contestou que a pergunta debatida não se encaixa nesses pontos. Como o @JorgeB. diz, parece que são mais *dislikes* do que está errado.

Comment: @JorgeB. Conconcordo com a diferença entre "ONDE" e "COMO", pois perguntar "COMO" atrai respostas que apresentem um **"Processo" para alcançar um Objetivo**, como um **Algoritmo**, e, é claro que cada pessoa pode responder uma Pergunta com seu próprio Processo/Algoritmo e achar que é melhor do que os dos outros (e pode ser), mas isso não classifica/desqualifica a resposta como "baseada em opinião" (mesmo que o Processo/Algoritmo seja a opinião que pessoa tem sobre a melhor forma de alcançar o Objetivo).